# Applying loadMask() to only grid pannel in extjs is not working

Tags: extjs, ria

I want to apply load mask to only my grid pannel using id of it,
    var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask({msg:"Please wait...",target:Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#grid')[0]});
                  myMask.show();
     But this doesn't seems to work.The same code is working for tab pannel. Please suggest the necessary changes in order to achieve load mask only for grid pannel.

```
//View code

Ext.define("DummyApp.view.grid.GenericGrid",{
    extend: "Ext.panel.Panel",
    requires: ['DummyApp.view.toolBar','DummyApp.view.formPanel','Ext.state.*','Ext.data.*'],
    controller: "genericGrid",
    alias:"widget.genericgrid",
    initComponent: function(){
        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: [this.createToolbar(),this.createGrid()]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);        
    },
     createToolbar: function(){
        this.toolbar = Ext.create('DummyApp.view.toolBar');
        return this.toolbar;
     },
     createGrid: function(){
        this.grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
            itemId: 'batchGrid',
            columnLines : true,
            selType: 'cellmodel',
            autoScroll :true,
            maxHeight:535,
            stateId: 'GridPanel',
            loadMask: true,
            stateful: true,
            bind:{
                store:'{genericGrid}'
            }       
        });
        return this.grid;
     }   


//Controller code
 renderData: function(genericGrid) {
          var store = Ext.create("DummyApp.store.GenericGrid"),
              gridId = genericGrid.up().gridId,
              serviceInput = Util.createServiceResponse(gridId);
              var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask({msg:"Please wait...",target: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#grid')[0]});
              myMask.show();
            Ext.Ajax.request({
              url: Util.localGridService,
              method: 'POST',
              headers: Util.createRequestHeaders(),
              jsonData: {
                  getConfigurationAndDataRequestType: serviceInput
              },
              success: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                    myMask.hide();
                  var data = Util.decodeJSON(conn.responseText);
                  store.setData(Util.formatGridData(data));
                  genericGrid.reconfigure(store, Util.formatGridMetaData(data));
              },
              failure: function(conn, response, options, eOpts) {
                 myMask.hide();
                  Util.showErrorMsg(conn.responseText);
              },
              scope: this
          });
          store.load();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, in your code grid have itemId is "batchGrid"(find by "#batchGrid"), your grid panel have alias is "genericgrid"(find by "genericgrid" because it is alias of component). Then just correct it, replace your itemId on correct name, **but better for this using needed component for target**

```
var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask({msg:"Please wait...",target: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#batchGrid')[0]});
```

better

```
renderData: function(genericGrid) {
   var store = Ext.create("DummyApp.store.GenericGrid"),
       grid = genericGrid.down('#batchGrid') // get grid
       ...

   var myMask = new Ext.LoadMask({msg:"Please wait...", target: grid /*or genericGrid for gridpanel*/ });
```

[**Fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/fp7)